# Does table (string, string) require index?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2

In my database running on SQL Server 2008 R2 I have a special table for global variables:

```
CREATE TABLE global_variables
(
    name NVARCHAR(50),
    value NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT PK_global_variables PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    name ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Does such table require indexing on `value` or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary key constraint creates an index (in this example, a clustered index) on the `name` column.

If you have queries that try to look up the `name` by giving the `value`, you'll need an index on `value` column to do that efficiently. Otherwise, if all of your lookups are based on `name`, you don't need to create an index on the `value` column.